# CSS vertically align and break text

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, centering, styling

I'm stuck at the point where can't align the text vertically and breaking two words apart in the middle of each circle.

For instance word "Classic Collection" needs to be broken down like below, aligned vertically and centred in the circle.

```
 Classic 
Collection
```

Wondering if someone could help me out to finish this out.

```
body {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
#coll_container .coll_item {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #333;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 105px;
    height: 105px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 3px #333;
}
#coll_container .coll_item a:hover {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
#coll_container .coll_item a span {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    padding:2px;
    border: solid 3px #fff;
}
#coll_container .coll_item:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color:#fff;
}
#coll_container .active {
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#coll_container .active a span {
    color:#fff;
    border: solid 3px #333;
}

<div id="coll_container">
      <ul class="coll_list">
        <li class="coll_item">
          <a title="title" class="collections"><span>Classic Collection</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="coll_item active">
          <a title="title" class="collections"><span>Ultimate Collection</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="coll_item">
          <a title="title" class="collections"><span>Luxurious Collection</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9Lte1mu/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the no-wrapping code

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

from the span and use flexbox

```css
body {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

#coll_container .coll_item {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 105px;
  height: 105px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 3px #333;
}

#coll_container .coll_item a:hover {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

#coll_container .coll_item a span {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    */
  word-wrap: normal;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#coll_container .coll_item:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

#coll_container .active {
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#coll_container .active a span {
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 3px #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="coll_container">
  <ul class="coll_list">
    <li class="coll_item">
      <a title="title" class="collections"><span>Classic Collection</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="coll_item active">
      <a title="title" class="collections"><span>Ultimate Collection</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="coll_item">
      <a title="title" class="collections"><span>Luxurious Collection</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

That stops the text from wrapping around.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/67vhq4gd/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do smth like this:

```
#coll_container .coll_item a span {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 font-weight: 600;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 95px;
 height: 95px;
 padding:2px;
 border: solid 3px #fff;}
```